# OpenMP and explicit thread interoperability when using OpenCV

Tags: multithreading, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, threadpool

I'm using OpenCV in a commercial application, and don't have management permission to purchase TBB licensing, so I built OpenCV with it OpenMP as the parallelism framework.

All the machine vision cameras we use as sources of frames we're processing in real-time have SDKs that fill frame buffers in a circular queue with data and call user-supplied callbacks to process them concurrently in threads of the SDKs' own thread pools.

This works fine when not considering OpenMP, as I'm doing a bunch of (memoryless) processing on individual frames before serializing them though interthread buffers to feed to the stateful processing stage where frames need to be processed in order. If it was just the concurrent frame processing, then I wouldn't need OpenMP at all; however, I need to leave it enabled in OpenCV so that the in-order frame processing is accelerated as well.

The concern I have is how well I can expect the OpenMP to work when it's used in the first phase, the concurrently executed callbacks in the threads created explicitly by the camera SDKs. Can I assume the OpenMP runtime is smart enough to use its thread pool in an efficient manner when there are parallel regions being triggered in multiple externally created threads?

The platform is guaranteed to be x86-64 (VC++15 or GCC).‎

Comment: If you hope for openmp thread pool to take your calling threads into account, you should use same thread implementation as openmp . Ms thread for ms or Intel libiomp pthread for libgomp

Comment: May require _OMP_NESTED

Comment: Or, replace those explicit threads with omp task , and use nested omp

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I'm not creating those threads but the camera libraries are. I don't have access to their source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Situation**

If I've understood the question properly, the camera library you're using will spawn a number of threads, and each one of those will call your callback function. Inside your callback you want to use OpenMP to accelerate that processing. The results of that are sent through some interthread channel to a pipeline of threads doing more processing.

If that's wrong, please ignore the rest of this answer!

**Rest Of Answer**

Using OpenMP in the callbacks would seem to be chopping the compute load of this part of your application up into little pieces for not much benefit. The camera library is already overlapping the processing of frames. Using OpenMP here is going to mean that the processing of frames doesn't actually overlap (but the camera library is still using multiple threads as if it does).

If it *does* still overlap, then logically speaking you haven't got enough cores in your system to keep up with the overall workload anyway (assuming your use of OpenMP resulted in all cores being maxed out processing a single frame)... I'm assuming that your system is succesfully keeping up with the flow of frames, and thereofre must have enough grunt to be able to do so.

So, I think it won't really be a question of will OpenMP be intelligent in its use of its threadpool; the threadpool will be dedicated to processing a single frame, and it will complete before the next frame arrives.

The non-overalapping does mean the latency is lower, which might be what you want. However you could achieve the same thing if the camera library used a single thread with your callback using OpenMP (and taking on the responsibility to complete before the next frame arrives). With less thread context switching going on it would even be a tiny bit quicker. So if you can stop the library spawning all those threads (maybe there's a config parameter, or environment variable, or some other part of its API), it might be worth it.

Comment: By intelligent I mean avoiding the oversubscription of thread pool threads to hardware threads. When openmp parallel region is reached, it generates some number of threads N depending on openmp settings, by default the hardware concurrency level. If openmp parallel regions are nested within each other, no extra threads are normally generated, unless omp_set_nested() is enabled. But if an openmp parallel region is within M externally created threads, one ends up with a total of N*M threads. So the issue is how to disable that. I may have found a workaround, which I'm going to post.

Comment: @DisplayName, yes I think left to its own devices you'd end up with N x M threads. But there's a difference between how many threads there are, and how many are actually trying to execute all at the same time. Of those N x M threads, I think you'll find that only N of them are running at any one point in time. Logically, if N threads cannot process a single frame within a single frame's time, then you haven't enough cores in the first place. Assuming that's not the case, then there will only ever be N threads executing. So you'd not be relying on OpenMP being "smart" - it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that the lack of guarantees as to the ordering of scheduling of execution of these threads means there will be more context switches, which is one of the problems of there being more threads. That could also decrease per-core cache locality. I will test for performance differences by using the omp sections workaround to cause OpenMP used by the library within the callback to only use one thread.

Comment: @DisplayName, surely the N threads that are running at once will be scheduled per core? N cores, N threads actually executing? The point is that a single M thread will run (and call your callback) only when there is a frame available for processing, and it's N threads will get through the frame's processing before the next frame has arrived. If they don't your computer needs more cores. So if another M thread is using a different threadpool for its set of N threads, those won't be running at the same time as another set of N threads. There's nothing for them to do until another frame arrives.

Comment: @DisplayName, effectively all your M threads will be blocking waiting for the camera hardware to deliver a frame. Only one of them will actually be running (the most recent one to get a frame), so only its set of N threads will be doing anything. The others are quiescent, not scheduled by the OS, because they're blocked waiting for a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code that explains a workaround I found. `LibraryFunction()` represents some function I can't modify that already uses OpenMP parallelization, such as something from OpenCV.

```
void LibraryFunction(int phase, mutex &mtx)
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> l{mtx};
        cerr << "Phase: " << phase << "\tTID: " << this_thread::get_id() << "\tOMP: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem of oversubscription with external threads is visible with this:

```
int main(void)
{
    omp_set_dynamic(thread::hardware_concurrency());
    omp_set_nested(0);
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(3);
    mutex mtx;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
            LibraryFunction(1, mtx);
        });
    }
    for (auto &t : threads) t.join();
    cerr << endl;
    LibraryFunction(2, mtx);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is:

```
Phase: 1        TID: 7812       OMP: 0
Phase: 1        TID: 3928       OMP: 0
Phase: 1        TID: 2984       OMP: 0
Phase: 1        TID: 9924       OMP: 1
Phase: 1        TID: 9560       OMP: 2
Phase: 1        TID: 2576       OMP: 1
Phase: 1        TID: 5380       OMP: 2
Phase: 1        TID: 3428       OMP: 1
Phase: 1        TID: 10096      OMP: 2

Phase: 2        TID: 9948       OMP: 0
Phase: 2        TID: 10096      OMP: 1
Phase: 2        TID: 3428       OMP: 2
```

Phase 1 represents execution of the OpenMPed library code in the camera SDK threads, whereas Phase 2 is OpenMPed library code used for later processing pipeline stages triggered from just one thread. The problem is obvious—the number of threads is multiplied by the nesting of OpenMP-in-external threads, and results in oversubscription during phase 1. Building OpenCV with OpenMP turned off, while fixing oversubscription in Phase 1, would on the other hand result in no acceleration of Phase 2.

The workaround I found is that wrapping the call to `LibraryFunction()` during phase 1 in `#pragma omp parallel sections {}` suppresses generation of threads within that particular call. Now the result is:

```
Phase: 1        TID: 3168       OMP: 0
Phase: 1        TID: 8888       OMP: 0
Phase: 1        TID: 5712       OMP: 0

Phase: 2        TID: 10232      OMP: 0
Phase: 2        TID: 5012       OMP: 1
Phase: 2        TID: 4224       OMP: 2
```

I haven't tested this with OpenCV yet, but I expect it to work.